# Query with aggregate, graphLookup and pipeline in mongoDb

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregate, pipeline, lookup

I have to manage a wall with comments, each wall have many parent comments and each parent comment have child comments.

my collection **walls** is like this

```
 groupId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'groups', unique: true},
    comments : [{
        commentId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'comments'},
        memberId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'members'},
    }],
```

and the collection **comments** is like this

```
text : String,
parentCommentId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'comments', default : null},
```

I want to display my wall by parent comments, each child comment under its parent comment.

but the result in mongo db isn't sorted all times, the sort seems to be random,

1- How to sort the childs array with field (childs.createdAt)

2- How to display only these fields under childs (_id / date / createdAt) and these fields (_id / childs / date) under array comments

**query**

```
db.walls.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      let: {
        commentIds: "$comments.commentId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$commentIds"
              ]
            },
            parentCommentId: null
          }
        },
        {
          $graphLookup: {
            from: "comments",
            startWith: "$_id",
            connectFromField: "parentCommentId",
            connectToField: "parentCommentId",
            as: "childs"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "comments"
    }
  }
])
```

**data**

https://mongoplayground.net/p/XTu0yeLTMMr

How can i modify my query ? thank you.

Comment: You can sort the `childs` array by unwinding and adding a sort stage after the graph lookup.

Comment: I don't think graphLookup is able to recurse in your data set because the parent document you are starting with does not have any links to the children.   Also connection from and to the same field in graphLookup will find all siblings, but not children of siblings.